# REPLACE Function In Apache Derby

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to update the current score in a table on Apache derby. If something already exists then I want it to update or replace the score with new one, and if nothing exists then I want it to insert.

I have written this so far and not sure what to use instead of REPLACE as that is giving me a SQL Error. The WHERE Statement is also giving me an error.

```
public void saveScore(int score) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String saveScore = ("REPLACE INTO USER_TABLE (USER_SCORE) VALUES (" + score + ") WHERE USER_TABLE.USER_NAME = '" + gameUsername + "'");
        statement.executeUpdate(saveScore);
        System.out.println("Score: " + score + " saved for " + gameUsername);
    }
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: When I use REPLACE I get `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "REPLACE" at line 1, column 1" ` and when I replace replace with insert I get `.java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE"`

Answer (score 1):

Derby doesn't have the `REPLACE INTO` statement from MySql: use `MERGE` instead.

See https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefsqljmerge.html